# NodeJS function readFileSync - do I pass "utf8" or {encoding: "utf8"}?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've found various answers to this on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.

Should I do this:

```
let data = fs.readFileSync(FILE_NAME, "utf8");
```

Or this:

```
let data = fs.readFileSync(FILE_NAME, {encoding: "utf8"});
```

?

Comment: Consider reading docs first, please:
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback

Comment: @KumarShubham: I have asked this question after reading the doc which you've linked. The exact answer to my question is not there, which is why I have asked it. Consider reading a question carefully before you suggest material which doesn't answer it!!!

Comment: The accepted answer gives straight reference from docs, Anyways, not your fault. Sorry :), It happens sometimes.

Comment: I guess the short answer is `Use 'utf8' when you don't need e.g. flags`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options), both are valid:

> ## fs.readFileSync(path[, options])
>
> - options <Object> | <string>
>
>   - encoding <string> | <null> Default: null
>   - flag <string> See support of file system flags. Default: 'r'.

The second argument may be either an options object, or an encoding name.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "options object"? Something like `{encoding: "utf8", flag: "r"}`?

Comment: An object with either or both of the specified keys: `encoding` and `flag`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to mention encoding explicitly,since it is an optional parameter

```
var fs = require("fs");

/***
 * implementation of readFileSync
 */
var data = fs.readFileSync('input.txt');
console.log(data.toString());
console.log("Program Ended");

/***
 * implementation of readFile 
 */
fs.readFile('input.txt', function (err, data) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
   console.log(data.toString());
});

console.log("Program Ended");
```

this worked even without providing "encoding" argument

Comment: I need to mention "utf8" because that's the format of the file.

Comment: I think node internally takes care about the file formatting.Not sure though.@goodvibration

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint 20.3, so UTF-8, Sublime Text 4 is also. Node 16.14 is also UTF8.  When II `fs.readFileSync` with no UTF-8 mentioned in options and having some ciryllic or accents in the source file, I have `<Buffer 69 6d 70 6f /... and so on ` .

I don't think it is optional. I mean you have to write it explicitly.